# Extension of a real valued function preserving given properties

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

Consider a function defined on a closed interval $f:[-a,a]\subseteq\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for some $a>0$. Suppose that:

1. $f$ is of class $C^2$ on $[-a,a]$,
2. there is $c>0$ such that $|f'(x)|\geq c$, $\forall x\in [-a,a]$.

Is there an **explicit** extension $g:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that:

A) $g(x)=f(x)$, $\forall x\in[-a,a]$,

B) $g$ satisfies properties 1. and 2. on the whole $\mathbb{R}$,

C) $g$ and $g'$ are globally Lipschitz.

Comment: Please show your work.

Comment: I can extend the function at the interval points by adequate affine functions and get all the properties but just class $C^1$. Alternatively, I can do something similar with adequate paraboles to get $C^2$ but in this case I loose property C).